# Magento 2 email validation error with zendframework validator

Tags: magento2, dependency-injection, zend-framework

I created an observer to send emails at a particular event. I used transport builder to send an email, but I get zendframework validator errors, but the email address is OK.

I was able to solve the issue editing the file: vendor\zendframework\zend-validator\src\EmailAddress.php in a local test environment but it is unuseful for a production env that relies on correct vendor based on composer files.

Then I tried a dependency injection in my module for the class related to this file but it won´t work.

Is this injection in di.xml valid for zend-framework validator ? I mean is Magento available to do that ?

Anyone knows another way to solve this issue ?

Thanks !

Comment: Validator is buggy, use simple mail()

Answer (score 0):

As far as I could understand Magento mailing system is a little buggy on version that I am using - 2.3.2.

I tried a dozen of different ways, and I finally came to a solution using old PHP friend original mail() function manually.

Even though it was not the way I intended, it works fine.